# Node js Cannot POST/ error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I had a working nodejs server.I was trying to modify it.I just changed the path inside the app.js file to the new file i have written.Now i keep getting cannot POST/ error.

app.get('/mypage', function(req, res)

to

app.get('/mynewpage', function(req, res)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the NodeJS documentation: http://www.nodejs.org/documentation/api/

Also, although you mentioned NodeJS I believe you are rather using Express, might want to have a look at that documentation too:
http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html

What Joakim tries to elude to is, that you maybe want to send a POST request to a GET method? Hence the POST/error

Answer (score 2):

```
// routes
app.get('/iGet', function(req, res) {
    res.send('GET!');
});
app.post('/iPost', function(req, res) {
    res.send('POST!');
});
```

Comment: Can you explain this?